# Error: No Match Function to Call

Tags: c++

I want to make my vector, vector_list, not to have any duplicate data. Here the code:

```
int is_Tally(int num ) 
{
    vector<int> vector_list;
    for(int i=1; i< 1000;i++)
    {
        int item = (i*num)%10000;
        if (vector_list.empty())
        {
            vector_list.push_back(item);
        }
        else
        {
            if (find(vector_list.begin(), vector_list.end(), item)!=vector_list.end())
            {
                vector_list.push_back(item);
                if (vector_list.size()>15)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return vector_list.size();
```

And I got an error when I execute the code.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*,     std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&)
```

Any suggestions? Thank.

Comment: can you show us code of "find" function?

Comment: @OMerObaid It's a standard library function pal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard library function [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is in the namespace `std`.

**Write `std::find`.**

Also don't forget to `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: I got it but the problem is not with std because I already use namespace, however, I forget to include algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (find(vector_list.begin(), vector_list.end(), item)!=vector_list.end())
```

It is complaining about this line of code. Apparently your find() function (not provided here) is not matching the way you have called it.

Make sure the find function has two parameters for a vector iterator followed by a parameter for an int, because this is what you are passing in your function call.

Also Note: Make sure the find function returns a vector iterator because that is what you are comparing it with using `!=`

Comment: "Not provided here"? It's provided by the standard library. It comes with the compiler. The OP just forgot to qualify it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for the comment, are you sure that the OP is using the find in the namespace std and not a function he or she has written? Because there is no include statement given in question, can you assume that is what they are trying to do?

Comment: Practice & experience =)

Answer (score 1):

Try including algorithm header. I think then It should Work.